# How to fix "Either assembly contains no tests or proper test driver has not been found."

Tags: nunit

I am getting error as mentioned Either assembly contains no tests or proper test driver has not been found.
When i enter "nunit3-console.exe project.dll".
I tried few solutions but it doesn't help me.

Comment: are you testing on a network share?

Answer (score 1):

Assumming you have not found a new bug in the NUnit engine, then one of the two things in the message is probably true...

1. You are running an assembly that has no tests
2. You are running an assembly with tests for which there is no driver installed, IOW tests that the engine does not know how to run.

These two things are combined in one message because it's really all one thing to the engine, which is basically telling you "I can't find anything that looks like a test to me."

Most likely, you do **not** have any NUnit3 tests, because knowledge of those is built into the engine itself. So, I would guess you are either running NUnit V2 tests or tests from some foreign framework, like xunit or microsoft test.

For more of an answer, please tell us what kind of tests you are running. What testing framework (and version) do your tests reference? If you are running NUnit V2 tests, do you have the V2 Framework Driver extension installed?

Comment: The engine (used by the console) is modular and uses a driver for each framework. The nunit 3 driver is built-in but no others are. The NUnit Project also has a driver for NUnit V2 tests, which you can install. In theory, somebody else could write a driver for a different framework, say xUnit.

Answer (score 0):

So... maybe there is a bug in the NUnit engine.

I had this exact same error message on my build server. At the same time the tests were running fine in Visual Studio (2015 with Resharper).

This happened when I started converting existing xunit to nunit tests in an assembly. As soon as I removed the last xunit test, the error went away.

Try to comment out everything except NUnit tests to see if this fixes the problem for you.

Answer (score 0):

As of Jan 2024 you may get this error when migrating to NUnit v4.x

In the Nunit release notes, https://docs.nunit.org/articles/nunit/release-notes/Nunit4.0-MigrationGuide.html, they warn that you must use the Nunit.Console 3.15.x and not use the 3.16 versions.

Per a discussion on their git repo, the 3.16 version doesn't work because of some other problems and the team has rolled back and is doing releases on the 3.15 codebase.

See https://github.com/nunit/docs/issues/875 for details.